# How to trace an object's path in libgdx?

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d

I have recently been working on a program which simulates gravitational interactions between planets. The physics have been implemented, and the program is fully functional.

However, the next feature to be added is the tracing of the planet's path, and I cannot think of a good way to do this.

The first way I thought of was to use particle effects, however that would require an inordinate amount of particles, and I believe that would bring very low performance.

The other way is by drawing a line between each position a planet has been through. However, this results in the number of lines drawn to rise to unreasonable high number, and thus performance greatly suffers, and in some cases, even by 1000%. Even when limiting the number of lines to a relatively low number of 300 per orbit, performance is lowered dramatically.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: How about a Mesh and do as many operations as you can in the shaders?
Shader operations should be super fast.

Comment: Also, are you are familiar with the concept of 'single instruction multiple data'? https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/people/geoff/cell/ps3-linux-docs/CellProgrammingTutorial/BasicsOfSIMDProgramming.html

Comment: I have not heard of this concept, but I will read about it. I am not familiar with meshes, either. Are they usable in 2D environments? Would I have to create a giant mesh that covers all possible coordinates?

Comment: A mesh in this context is a libgdx specific construct. It allows you to  push a lot of data to the graphics card with less performance impact. https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Meshes

Comment: yes, you can use meshes in 2d - libgdx uses opengl shaders for both 3d and 2d and shader based operations are where you get the big performance gains for graphics.